# SQL Where clause to select everything from a year

Tags: python, sql, filter, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, where-clause

I'm working with snowflake and python. I have 2 tables I'm joining which work fine!

The issue comes with the where clause. I want to filter for the year 2023.

The time column format is TIMESTAMP_NTZ format and the column data example: 2020-06-06 15:28:26.

I want everything, regardless of month, day and time to be filtered for the year 2023.

```
sf_query3 = f"SELECT * FROM {sf_table2} INNER JOIN {sf_table1} ON {sf_table2}.\"product_id\" = {sf_table1}.\"id\" WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM {sf_table2}.\"time\"::DATE) = 2023"
```

The above code is what I tried (and many other variations) but it's not filtering

Comment: Have you tried `WHERE time >= DATE '2023-01-01' AND time <= DATE '2023-12-31'`

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!
When you can't get something to work, a good approach is to simplify it until you have something working, and then evolve this to your target code. So just querying a single table with a single column:

```sql
create table foobars (date datetime );
insert into foobars values ('2023-10-10 18:45');
insert into foobars values ('2022-10-10 6:22');
insert into foobars values ('2023-1-10 16:01');

select * from foobars where year(date)='2023';
```

this returns the expected result (first and last record). Now you can create the join query and get it working.